# Trying to access a state object in mounted() in my Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vuex state that holds a user ID. In my component's `mounted()`, I try to use that user ID, but it's always `null`.

How do I get the state from my computed `mapGetters` into my `mounted()`?

Here's my `computed`:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('auth', [
    'userid'
  ])
}
```

And here's my `mounted()`:

```
mounted () {
  HTTP.get('account/' + this.userid + '/')
      .then((response) => {
        this.account = response.data
      })
}
```

The `this.userid` is always `null`.

BTW when I look at the Vue inspector, the `auth/userid` has the correct value in the getter `auth/userid`. How do I access `auth.userid` from `mounted()`?

Comment: This should work. The only issue I can think of is that the `auth/userid` getter *really is* null at the time it was accessed. Can you set a breakpoint on the `HTTP.get` line and confirm in the console that `this.$store.getters['auth/userid']` is not null?

Comment: @DaveMerwin Where do you set `auth/userid` to something non-`null`? Can you edit this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vn2q6q6v15?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue) to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`userid` might not be available at the time component is mounted. You can fix it by watching `userid` value, and only call HTTP request when `userid` is changed and available:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('auth', [
    'userid'
  ])
},
watch: {
  'userid': {
    handler (newVal) {
      if (newVal) { // check if userid is available
        this.getAccountInformation()
      }
    },
    immediate: true // make this watch function is called when component created
  }
},
methods: {
  getAccountInformation () {
    HTTP.get('account/' + this.userid + '/')
        .then((response) => {
          this.account = response.data
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

DEBUG

To debug this, first skip the `mapGetters`, and even `getters`, and return your state directly.

For example.

```
computed:{
   userId() { return this.$store.state.auth.userid }
}
```

I don't know how your store or modules are set up, so you might have to change things a bit.

Once that works, add it to your getters and use `this.$store.getters.userid`, or such.

Finally, when that works, try your original mapGetters and double check your module alias.

POSSIBLE ASYNC ISSUE

Now, on the other hand, if your getter is `async`, you will also get a null, before the userid promise resolves.  You would have to use an asyncComputed, or wait for the result in your mounted.